# How to construct jQuery object from variables storing html content

Tags: jquery

As question stated, would like to know is that possible to construct jQuery object from variables. Example as such:

```
var data = "<div id='bird'>halo world</div>";
console.log($("#bird",$(data)));​
```

JSfiddle link [provided](http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/nRQqh/).

Comment: `var data = "<div id='bird'>halo world</div>";`
`var items = [ $('#bird'), $(data) ​​];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(data)` will be constructed by `"<div id='bird'>halo world</div>"` , but you use wrong selector for selecting `"#bird"` element. `$("#bird",$(data))` searches within descendants of `$(data)` element.But as your `"#bird"` element is not a descendant of that object, you get an empty object. If you need to select `"#bird"` element, you can use [**.closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in this way:

```
$(data).closest("#bird")
```

Example:

```
var data = "<div id='bird'>halo world</div>"+
           "<div id='otherbird'>Other halo world</div>";
console.log( $(data).closest("#bird").html() );
//=>    halo world
```